# How to create 'available' funds in connected user's account for testing purposes?

Tags: stripe-payments

When manually testing and writing unit tests for Stripe Connect's Payouts API, it's proving difficult to test because a payout will only succeed if there's sufficient 'available' funds in the connected user's account. Moving funds into the connected account seems like a good idea, but those funds will be pending for some time before the become available, and AFAIK, there's no way to speed this up for testing.

Presently, the best solution I can come up with is to:

- Create a connected user
- Make a once-off very large transfer into that connected user's account
- Wait (typically 7-10 real world days) for it to go from being 'pending' to 'available'
- That will ensure there's ample funds in a connected account for testing purposes

Is there a better way - something instantaneous that doesn't involve a days'-long wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe provides several [test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) that allow you to skip the pending balance and have funds immediately available.

> 4000000000000077  Charge succeeds and funds will be added directly to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance).

> 4000003720000278   Charge succeeds and funds will be added directly to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance).